# How to install dependencies from requirements.txt in a Yocto recipe for a local Python project

Tags: python, pip, yocto, pypi, requirements.txt

## What I should have:

I want my Yocto Project to build a package for my Python project with all dependencies inside. The project has to run out of box on the resulting read-only sdcard image.
It simply should install all requirements in the required version to the package.

## What I tried without luck:

#### Calling `pip` in do_install():

"pip/pip3 is not found", even it's in RDEPENDS.
**Anyway, I really prefer this way.**

#### With `inherit pypi`:

When trying with `inherit pypi`, it tries to get also my local sources (my pyton project) from pypi. And I have always to copy the requirements to the recipe. **This is not my preferred way**.

#### Calling `pip` in pkg_postinst():

It tries to install the modules on first start and fails, because the system has no internet connection and it's a read-only system. It must run out of the box without installation on first boot time. **Does its stuff to late**.

## Where I'll get around:

There should be no need to change anything in the recipes when something changes in requirements.txt.

## Background information

I'm working with Yocto Rocko in a Linux environment.
In the Hostsystem, there is no pip installed. I want to run this one installed from RDEPENDS in the target system.

Building the Package (only this recipe) with:

```
bitbake myproject
```

Building the whole sdcard image:

```
bitbake myProject-image-base
```

## The recipe:

myproject.bb (relevant lines):

```
RDEPENDS_${PN} = "python3 python3-pip"

APP_SOURCES_DIR := "${@os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(d.getVar('FILE', True)) + '/../../../../app-sources')}"

FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"

SRC_URI = " \
    file://${APP_SOURCES_DIR}/myProject \
    ...
"

inherit allarch  # tried also with pypi and setuptools3 for the pypi way.

do_install() {  # Line 116
    install -d -m 0755 ${D}/myProject
    cp -R --no-dereference --preserve=mode,links -v ${APP_SOURCES_DIR}/myProject/* ${D}/myProject/
    pip3 install -r ${APP_SOURCES_DIR}/myProject/requirements.txt
    # Tried also python ${APP_SOURCES_DIR}/myProject/setup.py install
}

# Tried also this, but it's no option because the data MUST be included in the Package:
# pkg_postinst_${PN}() {
#     #!/bin/sh -e
#     pip3 install -r /myProject/requirements.txt
# }

FILES_${PN} = "/myProject/*"
```

## Resulting Errors:

Expected to install the listed modules from requirements.txt into the myProject package, so that the python app will run directly on the resulting readonly sdcard image.

With pip, I get:

```
| /*/tmp/work/*/myProject/0.1.0-r0/temp/run.do_install: 116: pip3: not found
| WARNING: exit code 127 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Function failed: do_install ...
```

When using pypi:

```
404 Not Found
ERROR: myProject-0.1.0-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure for URL: 'https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/source/m/myproject/myproject-0.1.0.tar.gz'. Unable to fetch URL from any source.
```

=> But it should not fetch myProject, since it is already local and nowhere remote.

Any ideas? What would be the best way to reach to a ready to use sdcard image without the need to change recipes when requirements.txt changes?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Yocto, but the syntax caught my eye, it's very similar to Gentoo's EAPI. In Gentoo's ebuilds, `RDEPENDS` declares runtime dependencies, so packages listed there won't be available at build time. Try adding `python3` & `python3-pip` to `DEPENDS` list instead.

Comment: As for the fetcher failure, `pip install -r requirements.txt` will try to download all packages listed in the file and install them. If you add `myproject` to the list of packages, it will make no exception. You can instead instruct `pip` to install from the source dir directly: `pip install path/to/dir`, where `path/to/dir` is the one containing the project's `setup.py` script.

Comment: Although I also might be completely wrong with my assumptions :-)

Comment: @hoefling: no, myProject doesn't make part of the listed packages in requirements.txt. But requirements.txt makes part of myProject. All the packages in the list should really be downloaded.

Comment: @hoefling: I also tried declaring pip in DEPENDS, but it has the same effect. I assume it searches pip in the host system that way I used it? Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You should use `RDEPENDS_${PN}` to take care of your dependencies for your app in the recipe.

For example, assuming your python app needs `aws-iot-device-sdk-python` module, you should add it to `RDEPENDS` in the recipe. In your case, it would be like this:

```
RDEPENDS_${PN} = "python3 \
                  python3-pip \
                  python3-aws-iot-device-sdk-python \
                 "
```

Here's the link showing the Python modules supported by OpenEmbedded Layer.
https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/layer/meta-python/

If the modules you need are not there, you will likely need to create recipes for the modules.

Comment: I have found very useful this script [PiP2Bitbake](https://github.com/robseb/PiP2Bitbake) script for generating the needed recipes

Answer (score 0):

**My newest findings:**

Yocto/bitbake seems to suppress interpreting the requirements, because this breaks automatic dependency resolving what could lead to conflicts.
**Reason:** The required modules from setup.py would not be stored as independent packages, but as part of my package. So, bitbake does not know about this modules what could conflict with other packages that probably requires same modules in different versions.

What was in my recipe:

```
MY_INSTALL_ARGS = "--root=${D} \
    --prefix=${prefix} \
    --install-lib=${PYTHON_SITEPACKAGES_DIR} \
    --install-data=${datadir}"

do_install() {
    PYTHONPATH=${PYTHON_SITEPACKAGES_DIR} \
    ${STAGING_BINDIR_NATIVE}/${PYTHON_PN}-native/${PYTHON_PN} setup.py install ${MY_INSTALL_ARGS}
}
```

If I execute this outside of bitbake as `python3 setup.py install ${MY_INSTALL_ARGS}`, all will be installed correctly, but in the recipe, no requirements are installed.
There is a parameter `--no-deps`, but I didn't find where it is set.

I think there could be one possibility to exploit the requirements out of setup.py:

- Find out where to disable `--no-deps` in the openembedded/poky layer for easy_install.
- Creating a separate PYTHON_SITEPACKAGES_DIR
- Install this separate PYTHON_SITEPACKAGES_DIR in eg the home directory as private python modules dir.

This way, no python module would trigger a conflict.

Since I do not have the time to experiment with this, I'll define now one recipe per requirement.

Answer (score -8):

You try installing pip?

**Debian**

```
apt-get install python-pip
apt-get install python3-pip
```

**Centos**

```
yum install python-pip
```

Comment: I know how to install pip, but I like to avoid installing pip in the _host system_ but using this one that is packed on build time, if this is possible.